# Oracle Sql to retrieve sum when match exists

Tags: sql, oracle

Sql help needed.

[image]

Totalcount= Employees + Count
The column names are like that. These are two random tables we are trying to join.
Imp: It is possible that - what exists in Table1 may not exist in Table2. Also what exists in table2 may not exist in Table1. So if exists in both then sum total needed, If not individual value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.company, t2.entity) as company,
       coalesce(t1.employees, 0) + coalesce(t2.count, 0) as totalcount
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t1.company = t2.entity
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select entity, sum(cnt) total_count
from (
    select entity, cnt from table2
    union all select company, employees from table1
) t
group by entity
order by entity
```

For this to work properly , you need the columns in both tables to have the same datatype, ie `table2.entity` should have the same datatype as `table1.company'` (as well as `table2.cnt` and `table1.employees`). If the datatypes do not match, you must explictly cast the columns to adujst.